# Windows Phone 7.1 "Send To" functionality?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7.1

I've been asked to write a prototype application in C# for Windows Phone 7.1 that can take data via functionality like Android's "Share" function and then process such data.

For example: The user opens the mail application and views a PDF attachment. For this attachment, he presses the application's "Share" button, selects my application from a list of registered handlers and my application can process the PDF file.

Questions:

1. Is such "Share" functionality available in Windows Phone 7.1 at all? (I way told it should be called "Send To")
2. Can somebody provide me with online reading on how to create respective handlers?

Answer (score 1):

I'm unfamiliar with the offering that Android gives, but you can extend the share picker and there is a [detailed article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967563%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) with example code to do so.

Comment: After reading the MSDN article I get the impression that this is only available to extend the gallery application. Am I right? Would this work for other applications, too, as I described in my example?

Comment: That depends on what you want to receive via the "share" - in the email app, clicking on an attachment doesn't give a choice of application to open in - the file associations are hard-coded and [not accessible to third parties](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sk/windowsphone7series/thread/8031feaa-7086-43e6-913c-3867274a569c). If you want to get a file association set up, you should be dealing with Microsoft directly