# Extending IE Sharepicker in Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone

There is a cool way to extend the share picker for photos in Windows Phone Mango, as detailed [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff967563%28v=vs.92%29.aspx). I would like to do this same thing for sharing web pages in IE, but it doesn't look like it's possible. Do you know of a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Windows Phone 7.1 "Send To" functionality?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10798962/50447)

Comment: Not a duplicate, Rowland. This one's for share a link not share a photo.